# Inserting a dash between two words

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to add a dash between the words Joint Stereo to show like this Joint-Stereo using regsub but just can't get the placement correct. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is the snippet

`if { $mode == "Joint Stereo" } { regsub {(Joint Stereo)} $mode {\1-} mode putlog "$mode" }`

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `if {$mode eq "Joint Stero"} { set mode Joint-Stereo }`?

Comment: Please consider editing the title of this post.  "Tcl Scripting Issue" is not specific enough to describe the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways:

```
set mode [regsub " " $mode "-"]         ;# replace the first space
set mode [string map {" " "-"} $mode]   ;# replace all spaces
set mode [join $mode "-"]               ;# replace all spaces
```

But Shawn's comment seems most appropriate